# WKWebView fallback to UIWebView in swift2?

Tags: swift2, xcode7, wkwebview

In my SWIFT project, I use WKWebView for iOS 8 and fall back to UIWebView for iOS 7, using this line of code:

```
var webView: WKWebView?
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIWebView!
```

However, this is not allowed in SWIFT 2 in the new Xcode 7. What is the best alternative if I still want to support iOS 7?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I added this dictionary to my info.plist.  Now the WKWebView loads as expected.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: You're a life saver! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the example code for just the purpose.

```
var subWKView: UIView?

//on view load, initiate the WKWebView and fall back to UIWebView
override func loadView() {
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        //this is only allowed to be used in the func block
        let webView: WKWebView!
        webView = WKWebView()
        //code for initiating WKWebView using addSubview
        //reference to the WKWebView
        self.subWKView = webView
    } else {
        //use UIView
    }
}

//Use WKWebView in other func blocks
func useWKWebView() {
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        //cast to WKWebView
        let webView = self.subWKView as! WKWebView
        //use the webView
    } else {
        //use UIView
    }
}
```